# How long does OpenShift Starter account provisioning take?

Tags: openshift, redhat

For about a week now, it says:

> Queued for provisioning
>
> Due to an increase in OpenShift Online Starter popularity, please
>   expect a longer delay in account provisioning. You will receive an
>   email when there is enough capacity to add your account. Thank you for
>   your patience!

Comment: Depends on which cluster you chose. Some are more popular than others. According to the status page, some are going through upgrades at the moment as well so they may have suspended adding new users.

Answer (score 7):

**Two weeks!**

It took two weeks for Red Hat to finally provision the account. Yesterday I finally received an email:

> Your OpenShift Online account is ready!

Obviously I had already moved to another provider in the meantime.

(Note that the status page had not displayed any technical reasoning for the delays. It was "all green". It's pretty obvious that this is just tactics to avoid getting users on the free tier.)